# Why would an inner static class extend the outer abstract class?

Tags: java

I am trying to extend some existing code that implements a tree using composite pattern. As expected from this pattern, there is an interface 
 (`Node`) and an abstract class (`AbstractNode`) representing a generic node. The latter is extended by multiple concrete types of nodes (`ConcreteNodeA`, `ConcreteNodeB`, `ConcreteNodeC`).

I encountered this other pattern in the code that I am working with, in which the concrete classes are implemented as static inner classes, extending the outer abstract class. And at the same time they implement static inner interfaces (`NodeA`, `NodeB`, `NodeC`) from the outer(?) interface `Node`.

```
public interface Node {
  public static interface NodeA {}
  public static interface NodeB {}
  public static interface NodeC {}
}

public abstract class AbstractNode implements Node {

  public void foo() {
    ...
  }

  public void bar() {
    ...
  }

  ...

  public static class ConcreteNodeA extends AbstractNode implements Node.NodeA {
    ...
  }

  public static class ConcreteNodeB extends AbstractNode implements Node.NodeB {
    ...
  }

  public static class ConcreteNodeC extends AbstractNode implements Node.NodeC {
    ...
  }
}
```

What is the use of this pattern? Through many years of experience with Java, I have never seen something like this before. My intuition says it is a massive code smell, as the concrete classes are constantly instantiated and used many times throughout the code. Anyway, I am not worried about efficiency, it is just that this is so difficult to mantain and extend!. It would make more sense to have them in separate classes, right?

I have searched for more formal references to prove it is bad idea to do it this way, but have not found anything yet.

There is no compiltation error, and the code works perfectly.

Comment: Having them as non-inner classes won't affect efficiency, if that's what you're worried about ("intensively used").

Comment: Oh no, I didn't mean it that way. I will edit. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is bothering you about this code? I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: "this is so difficult to mantain and extend" how so?

Comment: Aside: nested interfaces are always implicitly static. There is no need to mark them static.

Comment: It's a bit weird, but just a way to keep code together.. thats a matter of taste. I have seen and used this pattern for the class structure of AST nodes, e.g. where the abstract base class is `Expression`, and a lot of implementation classes as static inner classes (Divide, Multiply, etc..). [Link](https://github.com/software-engineering-amsterdam/multi-ql/blob/master/NickLodewijks/src/sc/ql/ast/Expression.java). In this case it actually feels natural to me, since the base class is not called `Abstract*`.

Comment: To provide an implementation of the abstract class, which can be returned by a builder?

Comment: I would actually argue that for the intended use, it is _easier_ to maintain and extend, because the author is implicitly sending you the signal that "these are all the subclasses of Node".  Had they each been in their own file (or worse, different packages, or even different modules), answering the question "can I add another node type" gets much harder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This pattern is actually quite common when describing related families of types, such as the nodes of a tree.

One reason is simply that it is a convenient grouping; these classes tend to be individually small, and having them all in one place can make it easier to read and maintain, as well as sending the signal that they are a tightly coupled family and intended to be used together.

A more compelling reason is that it can provide a form of *sealed classes*.  By having a private constructor in the abstract class, only the inner classes can access it, meaning that the inner classes are the *only* allowed subclasses.

Comment: I like this explanation.  Can you add a code snippet that demonstrates the sealed classes idea?  I'm having a bit of trouble pulling the pieces together in my head

Comment: A `final` class is one that can't be extended at all.  A _sealed_ class is a relaxation of this, where it can only be extended by a specific set of blessed subclasses (typically in the same compilation unit, sometimes in the same package.)  This allows you to reason about exhaustiveness; "a node is one of an ANode, BNode, or CNode."

Comment: @JulianCleary: I think Guava's [`Optional`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Optional.java) kind of demonstrates this pattern. It's "transparently" extended by two classes [`Absent`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Absent.java) and [`Present`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Present.java), which are in the same package. Noone else can extend `Optional`.

Comment: `enum` types with constants having a class body are an already existing example of such sealed types. So the sealed classes feature is a generalization of this pattern.